# How can we redirect all users to a particular page unless they are logged in?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a `admin.php` file which allows an administrator to perform various tasks by clicking on the respective submit buttons in the page.

I have an `employee.php` file which allows the employee to perform various tasks by clicking on the respective submit buttons in the page.

I also have a `login.php` file which allows the user to login, and based on the role of the user (admin OR employee), redirects the user to either `admin.php` or `employee.php`.

I would like to allow an admin or an employee to use the respective `admin.php` or `employee.php` only if he is logged in from the `login.php` file.

If a user directly types the url(say : `http://localhost/(folder name)/admin.php)` in his browser address bar, he should be redirected to the `login.php` page.

He should be allowed to use the respective admin/employee pages only if he is logged in .

Is it possible ?

Comment: first try something or add code which you have done before asking

Comment: Have a small login-checking script that gets included in every other script. If not logged in at right level, do a redirect via header.

Answer (score 0):

Like jeff said check your user's identity then you can use

`header('Location: mypage.php');`

to redirect him to the page you want